# Delphi TZipMaster - how to use the Find method?

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi XE, TZipMaster 1.91 (latest)

I want to get the file name of first file name matching the FSpec arg that is passed to the Find function. However, I get an access violation when calling this function.

```
  var
    DBBakFl : String;
    d : Integer;
  begin
    ZipMaster191.ZipFileName := 'myzip.zip';

    try
      DBBakFl := ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', d).FileName;
    except
      raise Exception.Create('Find raised an exception');
    end;
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
I sent an email got an almost immediate answer from one of the component's authors, Russell Peters. 
See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent an email got an almost immediate answer from one of the component's authors, Russell Peters:

> I am not surprise you get an AV
>
> ```
> var
>   Idx: Integer;
>   Entry: TZMDirEntry;
>    DBBakFl : String;
>  begin
>  try
>    Idx := -1;  // search from beginning, starts at Idx + 1
>    Index := ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', Idx);
>    if Index <> nil then
>       DBBakFl := Index .FileName;
>  except
>    raise Exception.Create('Find raised an exception');
>  end;
>
> OR
> var
>   Idx: Integer;
>    DBBakFl : String;
>  begin
>  try
>    Idx := -1;  // search from beginning, starts at Idx + 1
>    if ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', Idx) <> nil then
>       DBBakFl := ZipMaster191[Idx].FileName;
>  except
>    raise Exception.Create('Find raised an exception');
>  end;
>
> OR
>
> var
>   Idx: Integer;
>    DBBakFl : String;
>  begin
>  try
>    Idx := -1;  // search from beginning, starts at Idx + 1
>    ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', Idx) ;
>    if Idx >= 0 then
>       DBBakFl := ZipMaster191[Idx].FileName;
>  except
>    raise Exception.Create('Find raised an exception');
>  end;
>
> In a loop it is easy
>
> Idx := -1;
> while ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', Idx) <> nil do
> begin
>       DBBakFl := ZipMaster191[Idx].FileName;
> ```
>
> Russell Peters

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
 var
   DBBakFl : String;
   d : Integer;
   DirEntry: TZMDirEntry;
 begin
   ZipMaster191.ZipFileName := 'myzip.zip';

   DirEntry := ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', d);
   if Assigned(DirEntry) then
   begin
     DBBakF1 := DirEntry.FileName;
     ....
   end;
```

As find is failing, what you are effectively trying is to get the file name from a nil TZMDirEntry. Basically the same as:

```
var
  DBBakFl : String;
  DirEntry: TZMDirEntry;
begin

  DirEntry := nil;
  DBBakF1 := DirEntry.FileName;
end;
```

Comment: Why is Find returning nil even though there is an FBK file within the archive?

Comment: That is a different question, and one that is not so easy to answer.

Comment: @Rudy: Well I got the answer direct from the author Russell Peters, am just waiting for his permission to post the answer to this page.

Answer (score 1):

If the call to Find fails, you don't get back a valid TZMDirEntry instance, so you can't access the FileName property.

Try assigning the result of Find to a variable and check it for validity before trying to access its properties or methods.  Maybe something like this.  The documentation shows that TZMDirEntry is an abstract class, so you might need to use a descendent class instead.

```
  var
    DBBakFl : String;
    d : Integer;
    lDirEntry: TZMDirEntry;
  begin
    ZipMaster191.ZipFileName := 'myzip.zip';

    lDirEntry := ZipMaster191.Find('*.FBK', d);
    if Assigned(lDirEntry) then
      DBBakFl := lDirEntry.FileName
    else
      ShowMessage('file not found');
```

Comment: Yes. My question should have been: 'How can I make Find work?'

Comment: Check the return value of Find first.  I updated my answer with an untested suggestion.

Comment: @Bruce - while I was typing my untested suggestion!

Comment: This is more of a TZipMaster question rather than a Delphi question. Why is Find returning nil even though there is an FBK file within the archive?